# Block a hostname via windows firewall

Tags: windows-10, firewall, hostname

Is there a way to create an inbound rule at windows 10 firewall to block a hostname instead of its dynamic IP address ?

PS. I didn't care for modifying the hosts file

Comment: You are either going to need to use a different firewall (which supports blocking hostnames) or modify the hosts file to accomplish what you want.